# To select only one rectangle at a time in a loop with Corona SDK

Tags: loops, lua, coronasdk

I'm using the Corona SDK 2018.3319 on Windows to create a cards app, and have the following code:

```
local widget = require("widget")

scrollView = widget.newScrollView(
    {
      top = display.contentHeight - display.contentHeight * 55 / 100,
      left = 0,
      width = display.contentWidth,
      height = display.contentHeight * 55 / 100,
      scrollWidth = 600,
      horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
      scrollHeight = 1300,
      listener = scrollListener
    }
  ) 

local cards = {{name = "card1.png",x=8, y=8,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card2.png",x=84, y=8,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card3.png",x=160, y=8,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card4.png",x=236, y=8,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card5.png",x=8, y=106,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card6.png",x=84, y=106,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card7.png",x=160, y=106,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card8.png",x=236, y=106,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card9.png",x=8, y=204,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card10.png",x=84, y=204,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card11.png",x=160, y=204,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card12.png",x=236, y=204,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card13.png",x=8, y=302,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card14.png",x=84, y=302,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card15.png",x=160, y=302,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card16.png",x=236, y=302,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card17.png",x=8, y=400,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card18.png",x=84, y=400,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card19.png",x=160, y=400,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card20.png",x=236, y=400,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card21.png",x=8, y=498,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card22.png",x=84, y=498,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card23.png",x=160, y=498,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card24.png",x=236, y=498,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card25.png",x=8, y=596,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card26.png",x=84, y=596,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card27.png",x=160, y=596,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card28.png",x=236, y=596,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card29.png",x=8, y=694,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card30.png",x=84, y=694,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card31.png",x=160, y=694,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card32.png",x=236, y=694,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card33.png",x=8, y=796,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card34.png",x=84, y=796,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card35.png",x=160, y=796,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card36.png",x=236, y=796,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card37.png",x=8, y=894,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card38.png",x=84, y=894,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card39.png",x=160, y=894,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card40.png",x=236, y=894,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card41.png",x=8, y=992,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card42.png",x=84, y=992,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card43.png",x=160, y=992,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card44.png",x=236, y=992,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card45.png",x=8, y=1090,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card46.png",x=84, y=1090,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card47.png",x=160, y=1090,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card48.png",x=236, y=1090,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card49.png",x=8, y=1188,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card50.png",x=84, y=1188,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card51.png",x=160, y=1188,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card52.png",x=236, y=1188,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card53.png",x=8, y=1286,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card54.png",x=84, y=1286,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card55.png",x=160, y=1286,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card56.png",x=236, y=1286,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card57.png",x=8, y=1384,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card58.png",x=84, y=1384,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card59.png",x=160, y=1384,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card60.png",x=236, y=1384,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card61.png",x=8, y=1482,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card62.png",x=84, y=1482,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card63.png",x=160, y=1482,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card64.png",x=236, y=1482,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card65.png",x=8, y=1580,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card66.png",x=84, y=1580,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card67.png",x=160, y=1580,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card68.png",x=236, y=1580,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card69.png",x=8, y=1678,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card70.png",x=84, y=1678,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card71.png",x=160, y=1678,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card72.png",x=236, y=1678,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card73.png",x=8, y=1776,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card74.png",x=84, y=1776,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card75.png",x=160, y=1776,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card76.png",x=236, y=1776,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card77.png",x=8, y=1874,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card78.png",x=84, y=1874,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card79.png",x=160, y=1874,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card80.png",x=236, y=1874,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card81.png",x=8, y=1972,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card82.png",x=84, y=1972,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card83.png",x=160, y=1972,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card84.png",x=236, y=1972,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card85.png",x=8, y=2070,w=70,h=90, sel=false},
               {name = "card86.png",x=84, y=2070,w=70,h=90, sel=false}} 

local cardTouched = 0

local function touched(event)

  for i = 1,#cards do
    local card = event.target 
      if cards[i].sel == false and cardTouched  == 1 then
        card.alpha = .5
        cardTouched = cardTouched - 1
        cards[i].sel = true

      elseif cards[i].sel == false and cardTouched  == 0 then
        card.alpha = 1
        cardTouched = cardTouched + 1
        cards[i].sel = false

      end
    end
  end



for index = 1, 86 do
  local card = display.newRect(cards[index].x,cards[index].y,cards[index].w,cards[index].h)
  card.anchorX = 0
  card.anchorY = 0
  card:setFillColor(1,0,0)
  scrollView:insert(card)
  card:addEventListener("tap",touched)
end
```

I am creating 86 letters and I would like when touching one of them, it is opacity 0.5, but one at a time, and it is not possible to select two or more at a time. but I'm not able to do the logic inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need reference to tapped card to easily change opacity. I store reference to all cards in `myCardsRef` variable .
Try

```
local mFloor = math.floor   
local myCardsRef, cards = {}, {}
local lastTappedCard

scrollView = widget.newScrollView(
    {
      top = display.contentHeight - display.contentHeight * 55 / 100,
      left = 0,
      width = display.contentWidth,
      height = display.contentHeight * 55 / 100,
      scrollWidth = 600,
      horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
      scrollHeight = 1300,
      listener = scrollListener
    }
  ) 


for i=1, 86 do

    cards[#cards + 1] = { 
        name = 'card'..i..'.png', 
        x    = 8 + ( i - 1 ) % 4 * 76,
        y    = 8 + ( mFloor( ( i - 0.5 ) / 4 ) * 98 ),
        w    = 70,
        h    = 90
    }   

end 


local function tap( self, event )

    if lastTappedCard then

        myCardsRef[lastTappedCard].alpha = 1

    end 

    myCardsRef[self].alpha = 0.5
    lastTappedCard = self

end


for index = 1, #cards do

  local card = display.newRect(cards[index].x,cards[index].y,cards[index].w,cards[index].h)
  card.anchorX = 0
  card.anchorY = 0
  card:setFillColor( 1, 0, 0 )
  card.tap = tap
  card:addEventListener( "tap" )
  scrollView:insert( card )

  myCardsRef[card] = card

end
```

Note: I simplify `cards` table to save your time:)

Comment: It was perfect ldurniat, thank you very much for your help.